# Где найти провайдер для sqlite (EF6)?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, sqlite, entity-framework

Я хочу воспользоваться подходом Database first, используя sqlite. Но я никак не могу найти провайдер для него. Использую Visual studio 2019 (если это имеет значение)

Comment: [Оно](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite.EF6)?

Comment: Устанавливал ее сразу при создании проекта, все равно не находило нужное соединение. В общем, я уже вручную классы определил